# Itemize does not work

Tags: itemize

Why this does not work, please? The output is only h.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
h

\end{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item B
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\end{document}` ends the document, as the name says. You have it twice in your code. Everything after the first `\end{document}` is ignored.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document has two `\end{document}` instructions, which can't be right. Try removing the first instance of `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is due simply to a stray `\end{document}` in the middle of the code.

Comment: @ElenaGreg  please see the answer below to clarify the comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
hello
\begin{itemize}
\item Bravo
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you give some sort of explanation instead of just posting code?